# how to put for loop in the given batch file generating output text file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have a program which runs like this on the command prompt:

```
astroOrbit -p #1 > 1.txt
```

There are about 400 output text files to be generated with #-number going from 1 to 400 and the corresponding output file from 1.txt to 400.txt. How to put this in a for-loop from 1 to 400? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a command prompt window, enter `for /?` and read the output help.

From within command prompt window:

```
for /L %I in (1,1,400) do astroOrbit.exe -p #%I >%I.txt
```

From within a batch file:

```
for /L %%I in (1,1,400) do astroOrbit.exe -p #%%I >%%I.txt
```